# Make easiest dropdown menu using CSS HOVER

Tags: css, html

Actually I am new in web developing, and this question can be very easy, but please help me. 
Guys who can help. I am trying to make some dropdown menu while hovering on button.
What is wrong?

```css
.clicker {
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropdownKeeper {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 150px;
}
button:hover .dropdownKeeper {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="clicker">Click Me</button>
        <div class="dropdownKeeper">
            <a href="#">ajsghj</a>
            <a href="#">ajsghj</a>
            <a href="#">ajsghj</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try my code. May be this will help you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
button:hover~.dropdownKeeper{
      display: block;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: it worked, but can you please tell me what is doing the symbol "~" ?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use classname in css file, because you should have more of one button in your website.

```
button.clicker:hover + .dropdownKeeper {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.clicker {
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.dropdownKeeper {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0px;
  background:grey;
   width: 120px;
  text-align:center;
}
button:hover~.dropdownKeeper{
      display: block;
}
.dropdownKeeper a{
  display:block;
}
button:hover .dropdownKeeper {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="clicker">Click Me</button><br/>
        <div class="dropdownKeeper">
            <a href="#">ajsghj</a>
            <a href="#">ajsghj</a>
            <a href="#">ajsghj</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.clicker{
 border: none;
 height: 30px;
 width: 120px;
 background-color: orange;
 color: blue;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: absolute;
}

#dropdownKeeper{
 display: none;

    top: 15px;
    left: 150px;
}

button:hover + #dropdownKeeper{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>a</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <button class="clicker">Click Me</button>
  <select class="form-control" style="float:right" id="dropdownKeeper"  >
                        <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    </select>


</body>
</html>
```